# Combine two columns into a new vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have the following data:

```
Longitude  Latitude

-84.68934  59.22615
-84.52940  58.79971 
-84.68617  58.97750 
-84.88737  59.08489 
-84.71777  59.14207
-84.71777  59.14207
```

I'd like to add a third column:

```
Longitude Latitude Combined

-84.68934 59.22615 c(-84.68934,59.22615)

-84.52940 58.79971 c(-84.52940,58.7997)
```

*Edit - Pasting won't work (or at least I think it won't) as I need the result to be a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific about what you're trying do to?

If you just want another vector,

```
Combined <- c(Latitude, Longitude)
```

will work. If you're working in a `data.frame`, you probably are trying to do something that shouldn't be done, since `data.frame` values need to be atomic instances, not vectors.

Comment: For some reason, I was always getting an error that the resulting column has twice as many rows as the data.frame when I tried this method.  I was trying to get a list of Latitude and Longitude points as vector objects - c(Long, Lat) -  to use as in input to a function, but I just rewrote the function to take multiple parameters and used mapply.  I'd still like to know how to do this, though.